# SQL Server slow checking if linked server is online

Tags: sql-server

I have tried two methods for checking if a linked server is online, which are equally slow. Given I have to potentially check if hundreds of these linked servers configured are actually online, I am looking for a faster way to check availability. Unfortunately ping is not an option, since these servers are potentially shielded behind a firewall, where only the database port is opened.

```
Select 1 
Where Exists (Select COUNT(*) 
              From [LINK-RC].[DeltaV_KB].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES)

declare @retval bit
exec @retval = sys.sp_testlinkedserver [LINK-RC];
```

Comment: Would just connecting to the server be faster or is the overhead during the connecting process? Linked servers, in my experience, are really slow.

Comment: What may help (never tested) is tweaking the [remote login timeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms175136) (the default is 10 or 20 seconds depending on version). Beware that, obviously, setting this very low in production could cause unwanted timeouts if things just happen to be a little slow on a poor day. If possible, try doing this outside of SQL Server -- ping may not work, but connecting to port 1433 to check if it's reachable can be done with any number of tools, most prominently `nmap` (if your network administrators don't throw a hissy fit at its very mention).

Answer (score 0):

Change the *Connection Timeout* property of your linked server.

[Linked Server Properties (Server Options Page)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186839%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> **Connection Timeout**
>
> Time-out value in seconds for connecting to a
>   linked server. If 0, use the **sp_configure** defaultremote query timeout
>   Option value.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below, it may run faster. I guess if you convert your statement to Pass-through instead of the four part query, will run faster.
Also, you may remove the database and table name, because all you want is the connectivity with server.

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY ([LINK-RC], 'SELECT 1')
```

Comment: Tried this, unfortunately didn't seem to be any faster on my system.